# jQuery / ASP.NET - pass JSON file from ASP.NET to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have found a lot of solutions for going from javascript to ASP.NET, but I cannot figure out how to go the other way.

More specifically, my problem is that my company does not want to serve up the .json MIME type, so I have to use ASP.NET to fetch the JSON file from the file server. Currently I have jQuery that does a getJSON and traverses the JSON object to build certain elements of the page. Is there a way I can use ASP.NET (VB) to give the object to my jQuery script after I fetch it?

Comment: If you can set up any kind of service that can return a string (as text, HTML, whatever), if it's properly formatted JSON, jQuery can parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following three lines in the `ProcessRequest` of ashx file:

```
'Write the json to the response 
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
context.Response.Write(json)
```

This is assuming you already have a string called `json` with the message to be sent.

There are other ways to do it though, eg:

In JS, have something like (which helps if you don't need to do an AJAX call, but just want to pass a bunch of stuff to the javascript):

```
function processJSON() {
    var myObj = <%=Me.JSONProperty%>;
    ...
}
```

This should create the object without needing to be parsed.

Or you can fill a hidden field and parse the JSON out of it.